# Why are structured bindings in range-based for-loop just a copy and not a reference?

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I have the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cassert>
int main()
{
    struct Foo { int a; };
    std::unordered_map<int, Foo> foos{ { 0, { 3 } }, { 1, { 4 } } };
    for (auto &[i, foo] : foos)
    {
        foo.a = 6; //doesn't change foos[i].a
        assert(&foo.a == &foos[i].a); //does not pass
    }

    auto &[i, foo] = *foos.begin();
    foo.a = 7; //changes foo[0].a
    assert(&foo.a == &foos[0].a); //passes
}
```

**My question:**

Why doesn't the first assert statement pass while the second passes?
Why can't I change the value of a `foo` in the `foos` map in a range-based for-loop?

**Compiler:** MSVS++17 Visual studio 15.3.2

Edit: The code now compiles if copy pasted into a visual studio project.

Comment: MSVC bug. File a bug report.

Comment: Please post an example program that will compile.

Comment: @JiveDadson I edited my post.

Comment: I concur with T.C.  Looks like a bug. Inside the loop, it is treating "foo" as a by-value parameter.

Comment: Bonus bug: It sometimes crashes Intellisense (R). "Visual C++ Package Server has stopped working"

Comment: I filed a bug report. Once it is a confirmed bug I will post an answer. Yeej, my second msvc++ bug in like 2-3 months... My teacher recently said to me in response to a problem with his code that compiler bugs are so rare, we can dismiss such an explanation beforehand. Now I beg the differ.

Comment: @Jupiter The C++17 standard isn't even ISO approved yet. It is to be expected that brand new implementations of new features have some bugs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I posted a [bugreport](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102328/structured-binding-in-range-based-for-loop-is-not.html) in VS and it is under investigation now.